# Slow CPT in backend

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard

I have several CPT and I noticed that since I have now 100+ posts in some of them, the WP backend loads really slow but just in these CPT.

Other sections like Plugins, COmments, Settings etc. works properly.

Pages is slow as well ...

Following [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/wordpress-custom-post-type-admin-page-really-slow) I removed the `hierarchical` parameter, without any results.

I don't have any special plugin installed, just ACF and a chaching plugin. I tried deactivating all of them but same results. The PHP version is the most actual one, memory limit is set to 512mb.

What can be the issue here?

PS: the Theme I coded myself

Comment: Are you filtering the posts in any way? How many are you showing at once?

Comment: Try disabling ACF to see if that helps - it's been known to slow down the backend of sites. You can also install the Query Monitor plugin to see what's happening on those pages/CPTs resources/query-wise.

Comment: @JacobPeattie in Fronten-end yes, I am filtering them, but not in back-end. And I have no Categories defined.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what's slowing things down without seeing the code or Query Monitor, but one thing that could impact performance is meta. If you've added any of the ACF data / meta in custom columns, that would significantly slow down the CPT Listing page.

Comment: It may also just be your hosting; I've seen sites running terribly on hosting like GoDaddy because they've got a custom post-type or two with tons of entries, but then migrating them to something like WordPress dedicated (FlyWheel, Kinsta, etc.) pretty much doubles the performance.